# Como consumir uma API externa em Spring Boot

Tags: java, api, spring

Tenho uma aplicação em springboot REST que precisa extrair uma informação de outra aplicação. 
Como eu efetuo essa comunicação e posso extrair esses dados?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Você pode usar o [RestTemplate](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/) para isto.

Como exemplo, imagine que você quer fazer um GET para o sistema no endereço `www.sistema.com/api/` no serviço de `pedidos` de identificador igual a `10`. Você vai receber um Json com os atributos `nome` e `valor` deste pedido.

Assim, teríamos que criar uma classe no Java para receber estes valores, respeitando o mesmo formato do Json que receberá. Assim, podemos criar a seguinte classe:

```
class Pedido {
    private String nome;
    private BigDecimal valor;
    //gets e sets
}
```

E para chamar o serviço, é bem simples:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
Pedido pedido = restTemplate.getForObject("http://www.sistema.com/api/pedidos/10", Pedido.class);
```

O RestTemplate é bem flexível, o exemplo acima é bem básico. Se quiser fazer algo mais elaborado, como um `POST` passando alguns Headers Http, podemos [ter este cenário](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38388168/2387977):

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

MultiValueMap<String, String> map= new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
map.add("nome", "João Silva");
map.add("valor", new BigDecimal("1.00"));

HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(map, headers);

ResponseEntity<Pedido> response = restTemplate.postForEntity( url, request , Pedido.class )
```

Comment: essa solução é bem mais simples hehe

Answer (score 5):

Você precisa de uma classe do Spring chamada [RestTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-resttemplate). Um exemplo bem simples de um get:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(); //1
String url = "http://www.algumacoisa.com.br/api"; //2
ResponseEntity<String> response
  = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, String.class); //3
```

1 - Cria uma instância de RestTemplate
2 - A URL que você quer acessar
3 - A chamada propriamente dita. Como neste exemplo não estamos preocupados em mapear o response para um objeto, definimos que guardaremos esse response numa String mesmo.

Agora, supondo que você queira mapear o response direto para um objeto, setando nele os valores:

1- A classe que será populada com o response:

```
public class Foo implements Serializable {
    private long id;
 
    private String nome;
    //getters e setters
}
```

2- O método que consumirá a api. Note que o método usado é o `getForObject()`

```
Foo foo = restTemplate
  .getForObject(fooResourceUrl, Foo.class);
```

Fonte: [RestTemplate](http://www.baeldung.com/rest-template)

Comment: vaaaaleeeu, era isso que eu queria kkkk brigadão