# REST API usando Spring Boot

Tags: web-service, vue.js, rest, spring-boot

Como faço para trazer todos os dados de um serviço externo usando Spring Boot. Nunca fiz isso para trazer as informações. Já criei aplicações usando dados de um banco. Vi alguns tutoriais mas não obtive o resultado esperado.

O Serviço retorna estes dados:

```
{
    "dados": {
        "totalCount": 100,
        "dadosReais": [{
            "id": 0001,
            "anoApresentacao": 1995,
            "txtDescricao": "exemplo de descrição",
            etc...
        }]
     }
}
```

Meu mapeamento:

```
public class ClientRest{

private String dados;
private String dadosReais;
private long id;
private Date dataApresentacao;
private String txtDescricao;
//getters e setters
```

Minha chamada GET para o serviço:

```
public class ClienteServiceWs {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplateBuilder()
            .rootUri("https://www.exemplo.com.br/api/servico/v1").build();

  //ClientRest clientRest= restTemplate.getForObject("/", ClientRest.class);
  ResponseEntity<List<ClientRest>> exchange = restTemplate.exchange("/",
       HttpMethod.GET, null, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<ClientRest>>() {
});

  System.out.println(exchange.getBody());

}
```

}

Retorno:

```
10:08:19.436 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - HTTP GET https:/www.exemplo.com.br/api/servico/v1
10:08:19.462 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Accept=[application/json, application/+json]
10:08:19.793 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Response 200 OK
10:08:19.814 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Reading to [java.util.List<com.spring.boot.maven.vue.rest.ClientRest>]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Error while extracting response for type [java.util.List<com.spring.boot.maven.vue.rest.ClientRest>] and content type [application/json;charset=UTF-8]; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList<com.spring.boot.maven.vue.rest.ClientRest>` out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList<com.spring.boot.maven.vue.course.Proposicao>` out of START_OBJECT token


at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:1001)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:984)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:744)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:677)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:615)

Caused by: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList<com.spring.boot.maven.vue.rest.ClientRest>` out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList<com.spring.boot.maven.vue.rest.ClientRest>` out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:245)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:227)
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:104)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList<com.spring.boot.maven.vue.rest.ClientRest>` out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1442)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1216)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1168)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.handleNonArray(CollectionDeserializer.java:332)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:265)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:245)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:27)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4202)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3258)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:239)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como consumir uma API externa em Spring Boot](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/297405/como-consumir-uma-api-externa-em-spring-boot)

Comment: Seu mapeamento está errado. Na sua classe Java, você precisa de um objeto `Dados`, que dentro dele terá uma propriedade `totalCount` e uma lista de um objeto `DadosReais`, que dentro dele, por fim, terá as propriedades `id` etc. Na sua chamada usando `RestTemplate`, você não espera uma lista de `ClientRest`, mas sim um único objeto `ClientRest`.

Comment: Entendi. Obrigado. Vou tentar aqui...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa olhar o JSON como a representação de um objeto, e não como um conjunto de `Strings`. O erro acontece porque o Spring (no caso, o Jackson) não consegue achar um objeto que corresponda exatamente ao que ele espera.

Seu mapeamento deverá ser algo assim:

```
public class ClientRest {
    private Dados dados;

    //getters e setters
}

public class Dados {

    private int totalCount;
    private List<DadosReais> dadosReais;

    //getters e setters

}

public class DadosReais {

    private Long id;
    private LocalDate anoApresentacao;
    private String txtDescricao;

    //getters e setters
}
```

Depois disso, basta:

```
ClienteRest response = restTemplate.getForObject("sua-url-aqui", ClienteRest.class);
```